# Can I get a pointer to a pointer pointing to nullptr, is it valid

Tags: c++, dereference

I am having some doubts about the following code:

```
void b(int** a){
        int *c = new int;
        *a = c;
        **a = 120;
}

int main(){
        int *a = nullptr;
        b(&a);
        if(a)
                delete a;
        return 0;
}
```

My concern is that could cause UB, as it is a nullptr and I am changing the pointer address as I am getting an reference to it, but then I started to think that this should not be an issue as I will have.
Some address -> nullptr. And this some address is valid so I can change it.

I ran this test more than once and with the -fsanitize=address enabled and it works fine.
But, is this correct?

Comment: You have a memory leak, but that's about the only problem I can see.

Comment: Okay, true, will adjust that. But this is more a code to express the problem about getting the reference.

Comment: _"But, is this correct?"_ Yes, it's fine.

Comment: Keep in mind: double-star programmers are worse than single-star programmers, which are worse than no-star programmers.

Comment: Yep, I avoid that always. It is an existing API, not that I can do about that

Comment: @cheers except [three star programmers](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer), which are the best.

Comment: @Lefsler Still leaks. Did you forget the `{}` braces in that for loop?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf so when my c++ teacher said "well done give than man a star"  ... awwww.

Comment: I've even seen `double****` before. *"Well, it's a pointer to an array of matrices!"* XD

Comment: @BaummitAugen That has more stars than some of the hotels I stayed in.

Comment: @Ron, yeah, it is a demo :) But true, it is creating the int several times..... will remove the loop so it dont leak anymore , lol. The loop was to check if it would crash, but as you guys said, it is valid.

Comment: On a somewhat related note, you can `delete` a null pointer (it's a noop), no need for the check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My concern is that could cause UB, as it is a nullptr

The `a` that is the argument of `b()` is not `nullptr`, and it will assign the pointed pointer before dereferencing it, so this is not a concern.

Comment: to clarify: `b()` does not affect `nullptr` but only `a`, which has been initialized as `nullptr` but may be changed at will

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a memory leak, but you have to be VERY careful with things like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void b(int** a)
{
  int *c = new int;
  *a = c;
  **a = 120;

  // if C is deleted then the *a needs to be set to nullptr
  //delete c;
  //*a = nullptr;

  // Not needed as this will just be defeferenced off the stack
  // *a and c are two different pointers in memory so this is fine
  c = nullptr;
}

int main(){
  int *a = nullptr;
  std::cout << "Before B, a=" << a << std::endl;
  b(&a);
  std::cout << "After B, a=" << a << std::endl;
  std::cout << "After B, *a=" << *a << std::endl;
  if(a)
  {
    delete a;
  }

  // a still has a pointer with an address and can't be trusted
  std::cout << "End A, a=" << a << std::endl;
  // On repl.it, it prints 0
  std::cout << "End *a, a=" << *a << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c = nullptr;` is unnecessary since `c` goes out of scope immediately after. Furthermore, your last `cout` will incur the wrath of undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, comments say as much. I could also add that you can do 'a = nullptr' in b at the end and it won't matter.

Comment: Sure, I agree, this was like a small code to represent a problem, the pointer being passed, that is why it has so many flaws, as being a code done in a few minutes :)